# How to remove all tags except for some using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xslt, nokogiri

How do I remove all tags below a certain node except for some elements using Nokogiri?
For example, using this setup:

```
src = <<EOS
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello <i>world</i>!
      This is <em>another</em> line.
      <p><h3>And a paragraph <em>with</em> a heading.</h3></p>
      <b>Third line.</b>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
EOS

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(src)    
para = doc.at('//p')
```

How can I remove all elements in the paragraph (while preserving their content) except <i> and <b> elements?
So the result would be:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello <i>world</i>!
      This is another line.
      And a paragraph with a heading.
      <b>Third line.</b>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's more like an appropriate XSLT task.

Comment: Nokogiri also supports XSLT, so an XSLT example would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="em | p/p | h3">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your sample, result will be:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
      Hello 
            <i>world</i>!
      This is another line.
      And a paragraph with a heading.
            <b>Third line.</b>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT as requested in comments.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p//*[not(self::i or self::b)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will remove all elements (markup, not string-values) in `p`, except of `i` and `b` elements.

Comment: I tried it. It works for this specific example. But I am looking for a way to remove **all** tags except for some. This only removes the em, p/p and h3 from my example. Any ideas how to accomplish this? I am not too familiar with XSLT (I tried a match like *[not(name()='i')][not(name()='b')] but that does not produce the intended result)

Comment: This needs to show how to use Nokogiri with XSLT. More advanced Nokogiri users could figure it out, but that's not what SO is about.

Comment: @the Tin Man. that's why I posted only after OP said "an XSLT example would do".

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but SO is to help others who come along later also, because of a search showing there was something of use on this page.

Comment: @the Tin Man. I would've provided the full code, if I was anyhow familiar with Nokogiri or Ruby.

Comment: @the Tin Man: And what about people that have a Ruby enviroment but without Nokogiri? Is installing Nokogiri part of the answer? Then, how to run an XSLT tranformation with Nokogiri is a different question than this one.

Answer (score 4):

Just to round out the examples, here's one using Nokogiri without XSLT:

```
require 'nokogiri'

src = <<EOS
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello <i>world</i>!
      This is <em>another</em> line.
      <p><h3>And a paragraph <em>with</em> a heading.</h3></p>
      <b>Third line.</b>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
EOS

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(src)

if (doc.errors.any?)
  puts "doc.errors:"
  doc.errors.each do |e|
    puts "#{ e.line }: #{ e.to_s }"
  end
  puts
end

doc.search('//p/*').each do |n| 
  n.replace(n.content) unless (%w[i b].include?(n.name))
end

puts doc.to_html
# >> doc.errors:
# >> 6: Unexpected end tag : p
# >> 8: Unexpected end tag : p
# >> 
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >>     <p>
# >>       Hello <i>world</i>!
# >>       This is another line.
# >>       </p>
# >> <p></p>
# >> <h3>And a paragraph <em>with</em> a heading.</h3>
# >>       <b>Third line.</b>
# >>     
# >>   </body></html>
```

Notice that Nokogiri is not happy with the markup and did some fix-up. And, that the actual code to strip the tags was only three lines and could have been written on one.

Comment: An XPath variation: `doc.xpath('//p/*[not(name()="i" or name()="b")]')`

Comment: That XPath expression only selects direct children, but nested element is a classic content for (X)HTML... In the recursion lies the complexity, and the reason for an XSLT answer.

Answer (score 3):

Flack gave the correct answer using an XSLT template, I provide a full Nokogiri based example here:

```
xslt = <<EOS
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <template match="node() | @*">
        <copy>
            <apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </copy>
    </template>

    <template match="p//*[not(self::i or self::b)]">
        <apply-templates/>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
EOS

src = <<EOS
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello <i>world</i>!
      This is <em>another</em> line.
      <p><h3>And a paragraph <em>with</em> a heading.</h3></p>
      <b>Third line.</b>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
EOS

doc       = Nokogiri::XML(src)
paragraph = doc.at('p')

xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT(xslt)
transformed_paragraph = xslt.transform(paragraph)
paragraph.replace transformed_paragraph.children

puts doc
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello <i>world</i>!
      This is another line.
      And a paragraph with a heading.
      <b>Third line.</b>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the output generated.